# Decode HTML string

Tags: html, swift, decode

How can I decode my html string from:

```
<span>Bj&ouml;rn</span>
```

to

```
<span>Björn</span>
```

in Swift 3 ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Do you really need to preserve the `<span>` tags, while replacing the `&ouml;` symbol? One technique, suggested by Leo Dabus in [Convert Unicode symbol or its XML/HTML entities into its Unicode number in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32577960/1271826), converts the symbols includes round-tripping it through an attributed string.

In Swift 4:

```
extension String {
    /// Converts HTML string to a `NSAttributedString`

    var htmlAttributedString: NSAttributedString? {
        return try? NSAttributedString(data: Data(utf8), options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil)
    }
}
```

If you want an attributed string (for example, for use in a `UILabel`)

```
let string = "Bj&ouml;rn is <em>great</em> name"
label.attributedText = string.htmlAttributedString
```

This converts `Bj&ouml;rn` to `Björn` and italicizes the `<em>...</em>` portion, too.

If you just want to convert the HTML symbols and strip out the HTML tags (such as your `<span>`/`</span>`), just grab the `string`:

```
let string = "Bj&ouml;rn is <em>great</em> name"
if let result = string.htmlAttributedString?.string {
    print(result)   // "Björn is great name"
}
```

---

For prior Swift versions, see [previous revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/40116326/3) of this answer.

Comment: thanks a lot!!! it works

Comment: The `data(using: .utf8` piece in your example throws `use of unresolved identifier 'data'`. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Hi Rob and thank you. Strange, I use Swift 3 and still got that error.

Comment: You got an error that said "use of unresolved identifier 'data'" when you used that second example, which doesn't have a method called `data`? You've got some problem elsewhere then, because those are the Swift 2.3 and 3.0 implementations of this `String` `extension`.

Comment: Can you please tell how to use it with an encoded string?

Comment: I found this solution to be unstable in a multi-threaded situation.

Comment: I'd wager your instability rests elsewhere, because I just stress tested this in massively multi-threaded environment and it worked fine.

Comment: xcode 9 gives "Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled" when trying to use it as 'myString.convertHtmlSymbols()'

Comment: I've simplified this to eliminate error throwing. You can detect errors if the optional return value is `nil`.