# Convert all HTML entities to their applicable characters in SWIFT 3

Tags: html, swift, string

How do I convert, in SWIFT 3, the received text

```
StackOverflow&#174;
```

to

```
StackOverflow®
```

in order to display it properly?

Comment: When I Google `swift 3 decode HTML entities` there seems to be a number of results? Are they not helpful?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40116326/1271826