# Convert extension to function of class

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have extension to convert html symbols to string:

```
extension String {
    func convertHtmlSymbols() throws -> String? {
        guard let data = data(using: .utf8) else { return nil }
        return try NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil).string
    }        
}
```

This extension works good. But I need convert this extension to function in class "Converter":

```
class Converter{

    func convertHtmlSymbols(data: String) throws -> String? {
        guard let data = data(using: .utf8) else { return nil }
        return try NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil).string
    }
}
```

**But I got this error:**

> error: Cannot call value of non-function type

Comment: var text = try converter.convertHtmlSymbols(data: htmlText)!

Comment: what is `data(using: .utf8)` supposed to do?

Comment: I found this extension here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40113805/decode-html-string-in-swift-3

Comment: Better rename your variables/parameters to avoid confusion, but in your case it would be `guard let data = data.data(using: .utf8)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Martin R Suggested:

```
class Converter{

    func convertHtmlSymbols(input: String) throws -> String? {
        guard let data = input.data(using: .utf8) else { return nil }
        return try NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil).string
    }
}
```

The reason is

```
func data(using encoding: String.Encoding, allowLossyConversion: Bool = default) -> Data?
```

is a method used **on Strings**, in your String extension it is member of the String so it knows what to do with it, but in your `Converter` class it's not a member/property so it doesn't see it and can't use it.

See [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/string/1690799-data)

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 5):

In the `String` extension method,

```
guard let data = data(using: .utf8)
```

is a shortcut for

```
guard let data = self.data(using: .utf8)
```

i.e. the `data(using:)` method is called on `self`. In your class
you want to call it on the given string parameter (which also happens
to be called "data"), therefore it has to be

```
guard let data = data.data(using: .utf8)
```

Renaming the parameter can reduce the confusion!

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
class Converter{

  static func convertHtmlSymbols(_ string: String) throws -> String? {
    guard let data = string.data(using: .utf8) else { return nil }
    return try NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil).string
  }
}
```

And than call it like this:

```
try Converter.convertHtmlSymbols("your string here")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class Converter{

    func convertHtmlSymbols(data: String) throws -> String? {
        return try? NSAttributedString(data: data.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)!, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSHTMLTextDocumentType], documentAttributes: nil).string
    }
}
```