# Decode &#8220; Symbols In Swift 3.1

Tags: swift3, character-encoding

I am trying to show wordpress text in my UILabel. The problem is some characters are shown like **`&#8220;`**.
How can I fix this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Decode HTML string in Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40113805/decode-html-string-in-swift-3)

Comment: The accepted answer converts your encoded String to a _"_ symbol like a charm.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Unicode symbol or its XML/HTML entities into its Unicode number in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32577960/convert-unicode-symbol-or-its-xml-html-entities-into-its-unicode-number-in-swift)